# How to add custom controls to the Picture-in-Picture window?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on the meeting application and want to add a Picture-in-Picture feature as Google Meet has, but I can't realize how they added those controls like "Hang up", "Mute/Unmute" and Video buttons.

[image: meeting controlls]

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Picture-in-Picture_API

Comment: Oh, god, I was trying to find any info on whether it's possible to use `MediaSession.setActionHandler()` but didn't find any info about meeting controls for the first try.
But now I see that it's a right way, thanks @code

Comment: Yep, you can add controls with [`MediaSession.setActionHandler`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSession/setActionHandler), but you [can't set custom HTML button controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Picture-in-Picture_API#adding_controls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to add such controls using [`MediaSession.setActionHandler()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSession/setActionHandler)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).